# express.js require configuration

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having trouble requiring a configuration file in a node/express application I'm starting for learning purposes:

**structure**

```
app.js
-/config/environment.js
-/views
-/public
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var config = require('./config/enviroment')(app, express);
```

**environment.js**

```
module.exports = function(app, express) {
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade'); //extension of views
});
```

**error**

```
Error: Cannot find module './config/enviroment'
```

**stack**

- node v0.10.0
- npm  v1.2.14
- express.js 3.x

Sorry for asking such a simple question - it seems like it should work. I've checked file/directory permissions - everything seems in order. I'm able to serve views etc. from adjacent folders when I move the view configuration into app.js - so I don't think it's a permissions issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your require statement -

```
require('./config/enviroment')(app, express)
```

vs

```
require('./config/environment')(app, express)
```

Comment: Lol - working late! thx